# Selenium IE Driver locator - a tricky element Xpath or CSS

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I have a button on a page which I need to write a locator for - so far have been unsuccessful so would appreciate some help here :

```
<div class="border" style="border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<div>
<span id="btnAddClient" class="buttons">
<div id="clientContainer">
<div id="ClientAccordian_204" class="accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
<h3 id="H3Client_204" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" role="tabpanel" style="">
<span id="btnAddYear" class="buttons">
<button onclick="javascript:ShowHideAddYear(204,0);" style="float: right; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">
<button id="btnEditClient_204" title="Edit" style="float:right;">
<br>
</span>
<div id="yearsContainer_204">
</div>
</div>
<div id="ClientAccordian_210" class="accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
<h3 id="H3Client_210" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" role="tabpanel" style="">
<span id="btnAddYear" class="buttons">
<button onclick="javascript:ShowHideAddYear(210,0);" style="float: right; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">
<button id="btnEditClient_210" title="Edit" style="float:right;">
<br>
</span>
<div id="yearsContainer_210">
</div>
</div>
<div id="ClientAccordian_209" class="accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
<div id="ClientAccordian_211" class="accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
<div id="ClientAccordian_215" class="accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
<h3 id="H3Client_215" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" role="tabpanel" style="">
<span id="btnAddYear" class="buttons">
<button onclick="javascript:ShowHideAddYear(215,0);" style="float: right; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">
<button id="btnEditClient_215" title="Edit" style="float:right;">
<br>
</span>
<div id="yearsContainer_215"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

On this page 3 of these button appear but there could be more `<button onclick="javascript:ShowHideAddYear(i,j)..>`

Common locators like `css=#btnAddYear > button` or `//span[@id=’btnAddYear’]/button[text()=’Add Year’]` do not work. Can someone help writing a reliable locator that selects the button uniquely ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your input folks, I treid various things like tabbing to the element and firing an "enter" event etc but nothing worked. This turned out to be an issue with Selenium IE Driver. http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5142

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the text 'Add Year' in the html you provided. Does it work if you change it to  //span[@id=’btnAddYear’]/button[1]?

Comment: XPath uses 1-based indexers, as opposed to 0-based (as in C# etc). That is to say that the first element in an XPath list would be [1], not [0].

Comment: Hi Spencer, thanks for the response, sadly button[0] doesnt work either. Also thetext is found as seen below under each span. <button onclick="javascript:ShowHideAddYear(215,0);" style="float:right;">
<img src="/abc/Content/icons/calendar_add.png">
Add Year
</button>

Comment: Like Arran said, try [1]

Comment: Thank you Arran, [1] doesnt work - just says "cannot be evaluated or does not result in a WebElement" which i have heard is an issue with IE8. When i inspect the Span element using say firebug it does not highlight any area in the page so could also be that our locator using //span is not appropriate - do we have another alternative ?

Comment: Which one of the buttons are you targetting?

Comment: This is the thing Paul, it will be decided at runtime a bit randomly but to answer your question for now its "button onclick="javascript:ShowHideAddYear(210,0);" but I cant rely on the "210" bit..

Comment: @PaulSmith, when does it give that error message? Show the exact code you are running. Is this in the Selenium IDE or some WebDriver code? When you say run it in IE8, well, where are you running it? Is it through some code?  ....and looking at Spencer's XPath, it *might* be a bit better as this: `(//span[@id='btnAddYear']//button)[1]`

Comment: Arran, its run using Selenium IE Driver as a console program from VS2010. Its an issue with the IE Driver itself and goes into the known issues bucket of the "work in progress" tool called selenium! #Frustration

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
'//span[@id="btnAddYear"]//button[contains(., "Add Year")]'
```

Comment: //span[@id='btnAddYear']/button[contains(., 'Add Year')] does not work.. using //span doesnt seem to work.. just doesnt see the object even when its present !